# Plotted candlestick chart disappears after plotting additional data

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, mplfinance

I'm building a bot that analyzes my trades in the stock market. I have two axes, one plotting my trade orders, and one plotting the candlestick chart of the traded stock.

```py
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2)

# Plotting Trades
ax1.plot(...)

# Plotting Candlestick Chart
mpf.plot(stock.data, ax=ax2, type='candle')
ax2.set_title(f'Stock History of {stock.symbol}')
ax2.set_xlabel('Date')
ax2.set_ylabel('Price')
```

This works fine so far and plots the chart as envisioned.
[image]

However, I'd now like to add markers to the chart for when I entered and exited trades. To start simple, I took all the orders and put all dates and prices in separate lists, so that I could specify the X as the dates and Y as the prices.

```py
# Plotting Orders
dates, prices = [], []
for key, order in broker.orders.items():
    dates.append(order.date)
    prices.append(order.price)
ax2.plot(dates, prices, 'o')
```

But instead, now the chart was completely gone and all I could see was the markers.[image]

Even the dates are not showing up which is a bit confusing since I splitted up the dates in its own specific list so that the X-positions would still be correct.

**Anyone who has an idea of what's going on here? Thanks beforehand.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `mpf.plot(..., ax=ax2)` and `ax2.plot(...)` override some important plot settings of each other. You should probably add your orders data with [mplfinance.make_addplot()](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/blob/master/examples/addplot.ipynb) like this:

```py
import mplfinance as mpf
import yfinance as yf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# market data
df = yf.download("SPY", start="2024-02-13", end="2024-02-14", interval='1h')

# some fake data
d = {
    'dates': ['2024-02-13 09:30:00', '2024-02-13 10:30:00', '2024-02-13 11:30:00', '2024-02-13 12:30:00', '2024-02-13 13:30:00', '2024-02-13 14:30:00', '2024-02-13 15:30:00'],
    'prices': [493.5, 495.2, 495.8, 494.8, 492.0, 492.6, 493.0]
}
my_df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

# show everything on one plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
my_dict = mpf.make_addplot(my_df['prices'], type='scatter', ax=ax)
mpf.plot(df,
         ax=ax,
         type="candle",
         addplot=my_dict
    )

plt.show()
```

The code produces the following image:

[image]

**UPDATE**

If your orders data is available only for some of the stock market timestamps, then you could make a combined dataframe with a price column having `NaN` values in the rows, where orders data is "missing". In this way you would have two data frames of equal length, suitable to be shown on one plot with `mpf.make_addplot()` and `mpf.plot()`:

```py
import mplfinance as mpf
import yfinance as yf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# get market data
df = yf.download("SPY", start="2024-02-13", end="2024-02-14", interval="1h")

# make some fake data with the same time format as market data
my_prices = [493.5, 495.2, 495.8]
# these timestamps must be a subset of those from the market data
my_timestamps = pd.date_range("2024-02-13 09:30:00", periods=len(my_prices), freq="H", tz="America/New_York")
d = {
# this column must be named the same way as the column with timestamps from the market data
    "Datetime": my_timestamps,
    "Prices": my_prices
}
my_df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

# merge data sets, resulting in a new column with prices, where prices for missing market dates are NaN
combined_df = df.merge(my_df, how="outer", on="Datetime")

# show everything on one plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
my_dict = mpf.make_addplot(combined_df["Prices"], type="scatter", color="red", ax=ax)
mpf.plot(df,
         ax=ax,
         type="candle",
         addplot=my_dict
    )

plt.show()
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Comment: I'm getting this error:
`ValueError: x and y must be the same size`

Comment: Apparently, your stock and orders data have different lengths, which is not allowed by `mpf.plot()`. Perhaps you could pad one of those data sets with some dummy values to equalize their sizes. Alternatively, you could try to make your own candlestick chart with the matplotlib box plot: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/statistics/boxplot.html#sphx-glr-gallery-statistics-boxplot-py

Comment: I see. Yes, they have similar lengths since I don't trade every day. If you look in the mplfinance documentation for the addplot functions, `In [7]` covers a way to scatter trading signals on the chart. Perhaps I can do something similar but with my order data instead?

https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/blob/master/examples/addplot.ipynb

Comment: It looks like they extract a subset `tdf` of their original data set and then make a list of values `signal`, which is of exactly the same length as `tdf`, but has `np.nan` values at some dates. Then they show the `tdf` data with `mpf.plot()`, adding `signal` with `mpf.make_addplot()`. So you should probably insert `np.nan` values in your orders data, for the dates you are not trading, and plot them in a similar way.

Comment: I tried generating a new data frame with `NaN` values in place of the missing prices, and it seems to be working. Please, check the update part of my answer above.

Comment: Yes, I tried as well. It worked.

Comment: Cool man, saw your updated script. Your method was a lot easier to include the `np.nan` values. I did it manually at first lol. Thank you.